# get data from 2 mysql tables with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, contacts and contacts_group. contacts has (id, name, lastname, email,), contacts_group has (id, owner, mail, group_name). How can i select this together with php.

Comment: Much more information is needed. What MySQL API are you using in PHP (MySQLi, PDO)? How are those tables related? What kind of data do you intend to display?

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 2):

You should have a foreign key in `contacts` which refers to `id` in `contacts_group`, then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts_group cg JOIN contacts c ON c.id_group = cg.id
```

You should read about relationships in MySQL ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hans, you could use two different queries:

```
$contactsquery = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
$contacts_group_query = "SELECT * FROM contacts_group";
```

Of course you would need a DB Connection on top:

```
define("DB_SERVER","localhost");
define("DB_USER","chatApp");
define("DB_PASS","ibmpass");
define("DB_NAME","chatApp");

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
```

And to perform them you would use

```
$result_1 = mysqli_query($connection, $contactsquery);
$result_2 = mysqli_query($connection, $contacts_group_query);
```

Or you could create a foreign key on the `contacts_group` to keep track of the contacts, and then join them in code as:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts_group cg JOIN contacts c ON c.id_group = cg.id
```

But I would **highly recommend** you to read this [basic introduction to PHP & Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) before getting deeper, as you will have many doubts about it.